# How to transform target.value on an action bound to an event listener?

Tags: ember.js

When using actions on html event handlers, for example:

```
<input value={{editor.strokeWidth}}
   oninput={{action (mut editor.strokeWidth) value=target.value}}>
```

is there any way to transform target.value declaratively in the template?

In particular, for some editor values I need to `parseInt`, for others `parseFloat`.

I'd like to be able to do something like this (non-working, but conveys what I want to accomplish):

```
<input value={{editor.strokeWidth}}
   oninput={{action (mut editor.strokeWidth) value=(as-float target.value)}}>
```

given that I have an as-float helper defined.

The reason I want to avoid doing the transformation in the editor object is that that object is a proxy for a third party object which has an api with a large surface area; if the third party api adds properties I don't want users of my add-on to have to wait for an update to be able to add inputs that access them.

Comment: I have done a hacky thing, which works but is ugly: I append any needed parser to the key path with a hyphen: `(mut editor.strokeWidth-asFloat)` and  look for it in the `setUnknownProperty` of the editor object (which I already needed to handle delegating get/set to the third-party object anyway). I still hope there may be a "proper" way to do it.

Comment: What about using a custom `input` component? you could define a custom `oninput` that transforms the value depending on certain circumstances.

Comment: @HenryVonfire two reasons: first, I want one-way DDAU semantics but had much trouble figuring out how to do that without rewriting the input component from scratch, and second I want users of the add-on to be able to easily build their own widgets using any html of their choice. The proxy object is working -- it would be horrific with two way binding, but it seems manageable with DDAU.

Comment: You do not need to rewrite it, there is an addon already made https://github.com/dockyard/ember-one-way-input